# background-size: cover stretched on mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I'm using multiple sections on one-page-layout website. Every second section uses background image:

```
<body>
    <section id="one" class="banner"></section>
    <section id="two"></section>
    <section id="three" class="style1"></section>
    <section id="four"></section>
    <section id="five" class="style2"></section>
    <section id="six"></section>
</body>
```

Where banner has fixed height, so `background-size: cover` works fine on all browsers, where desktops have `background-attachment: fixed` and < 1024px have `background-attachment: scroll`.

Problem is, that *`style1`* and *`style2`* have content with variable height and the image is stretched to height of the section, not to the height of the viewport as it should.

This is my CSS for style1-3 blocks:

```
.style1, .style2, .style3 {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
.style1 {
    background-image: url('../../images/2.jpg');
}
.style2 {
    background-image: url('../../images/3.jpg');
}
.style3 {
    background-image: url('../../images/4.jpg');
}
```

I've tried to use jQuery to inject `<img/>` with `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; min-height: 100%; min-width: 100%;` and other solutions here on SO, but all I ended up with was that all images were positioned on top covering banner and only last image was visible.

This happens on Chrome mobile, Safari mobile but not on Edge browser on W10M (there it works the same as on desktop).

Comment: in `iOS`, `background-attachment: fixed` will failure, because this will redraw when scroll, so we use `z-index: -1 img` to fix this. But I don't know your question? Could you give the demo in jsfiddle?

Comment: "`< 1024px have background-attachment: scroll`" .. the question is, how to fix the issue with background stretched to container height instead of viewport height ..

Comment: use `img` to `background`, then change the `z-index` of them. Maybe this can help you, but I can't understand you well.

Comment: what about `background-size: auto 100vh;` this will set the background to the height of the view port

Comment: Thank you guys, but none of these solutions work. image in background (for example div) with z-index doesn't work as there is some logic missing for swapping the z-index while scrolling. background-size: auto 100vh; can adjust the image (although I must create separate image set for portrait), but it stays in the middle of whole section, so there is large white space above and below the image

Comment: @RPichioli so you moderated my post only by adding spaces to text indent (4 spaces instead of 2) and  changed one letter to capital. This is disgusting way of gathering points on SO and I'm shocked it's tolerated!

Comment: @moped it's not whitespaces, you have to mind in a clear and correct code indentation in edits, i look for that and it's what i've done. Your comment sounds a bit offensive, peace bro. Questions and answers must be clear, objective, etc.. more about in: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Sorry anyway.